# Doctrine retrieve entity data with one to many association

Tags: doctrine-orm

i want to fetch the data of a menu including its categories in a custom repository by a dql-statement, but it doesn't return the associated entities. I need it as json data, so i added the hydration mode **Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY** to the function call.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Company\Repository\Doctrine\MenuRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="menu")
 */
class Menu {
    /**
     * @var \Company\Entity\MenuCategory[]
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Company\Entity\MenuCategory", mappedBy="menu")
     */
    protected $categories;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Company\Repository\Doctrine\MenuCategoryRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="menu_category")
 */
class MenuCategory {
    /**
     * @var \Company\Entity\Menu
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Company\Entity\Menu", inversedBy="categories")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    protected $menu;
}

class MenuRepository extends EntityRepository implements MenuRepositoryInterface {

    public function findById($id, $hydration = Query::HYDRATE_OBJECT) {
        $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('menu')
            ->leftJoin('menu.categories', 'categories')
            ->where('menu.id = :menuId')
            ->setParameter('menuId', $id);

        return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getSingleResult($hydration);
    }

}
```

The result looks like that:

```
array(4) {
   ["id"]=>int(1)
   ["name"]=> string(6) "Test"
}
```

Comment: What menus and categories do you expect/are in your database? Since you want to query categories rather than menus, you should start by selecting category where menu...

Comment: Add to your query builder:  ->addSelect('categories')

Comment: Thanks Cerad, that was the mistake. If i dont select them, they dont will be in the result :) Sometimes it's so easy...